# How to store variables for the next time a program runs

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a program that reports how many times a customer has visited between a certain our of the day.  In this case, the program runs each day, to find out how many customers came in between the hours of 6 and 7.  The problem I'm running into is I also need to keep a running tally of the number of customers visted between the hours.  So I need the output to look like:

```
Today: 5
Total: 5

Today: 5
Total: 10

Today 5
Total 15
```

I can store the info in an XML file, but I have 16 different locations I'm tracking so that's a lot of writing, and reading from an xml file, so I assume there is a better way to handle this?  I basically need the program to load the value of the "total" which is Today, plus previous days.

I fill the values like this:

```
  firsthour = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(x)
    secondhour = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(x)
    Percentage = Math.Round(ds2.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(x) / ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(x) * 100, 2)
    firsthourtotal = ds.tables(0).Rows(i).item(x)
    secondhourtotal = ds2.tables(0).Rows(i).item(x)
```

Obviously, I need the `Fisthourtotal`, `secondhourtotal`, to be stored for each of the 16 results in the array, to be accessed each day when the program runs.

Comment: have you looked at `My.Settings`?

Comment: I have not.  i'll have to look at it.

Comment: If you decide to not use My.Settings (which is what I would do), there's also the option of Binary or XML serialization.

Comment: If you already have a link to a SQL server, couldn't you store the information there?

Comment: I'm not able to write to the SQL database.  Read Only.

Comment: What kind of application are you talking about? It is a desktop application or a web app?

Comment: @Plutonix If I am not in error, My.Settings allows to write only the User settings. These seems to be values valid for the whole application not different for each user.

Comment: It's a desktop application. I'll Update my question with a little more info.

Comment: if thats the case, an ancillary database might be better depending on (locations * number of Customers)

Comment: Create another database if the other database is read-only. This is not something you should try to store in a file.

Comment: I'm pulling the info from 16 separate databases.

Comment: when you say `how many times a customer ...` do you literally mean a single, specific customer? or something else

Comment: just total number of visits (all customers).  So for example, if we had 5 customers visit between 6-7, then we would want it to report '5'.

Comment: but you arent storing the customer count for each hour, just the daily total apparently?

Comment: just the dailytotal for that specific hour.  which is why I can't just run a mass query to get a date range.  My sql query is 'where dtcreated between '10/16/14 06:00:00' and '10/16/14 07:00:00'  I can't run a query for 10/16/14 - 11/1/14 ONLY for the hours of 6-7 each day.

Comment: I'd do that quite differently and store the Date and count; managers who ask for this type of info **always** end up changing what they want to know and will want rolling averages or avg by day of week which a simple total wont handle.  SOmething like {Location, Date, Count}

Comment: How do you mean you'd store it differently?  What would you change?

Comment: Its mentioned at the end: {Location, Date, Count} so that the count is associated with the meaningful identifiers.  The grand total is not very interesting because you can always calculate that

Comment: right, but where would it be stored?

Comment: some small DB for that purpose probably (not a lot to go on here).  a serialized class could work but like I said these things tend to grow (*if we can track 6-7 why not all the hours!?!?!! yes! lets do that! and **fries** how many fries were sold...and*)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way but....

If I was doing it I would use `My.Settings` and use the `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` type for the situation described.

Nice and easy to read and write to, just remember to `My.Settings.Save` after writing to it otherwise it will wait till you close the application before updating the record!